# How can I add lines in a file from another file using awk or sed

Tags: awk, lines

I have 2 files:
  File 1:

```
  1012055500012221
  2011052210011021
  3010051501010221
  4015051510012201
```

File 2:

```
  50222111
  60202100
  75222105
  90202125
```

I want:

```
   1012055500012221
   2011052210011021
   3010051501010221
   4015051510012201
   50222111
   60202100
   75222105
   90202125
```

How can I do that in awk or sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need awk/sed when

```
cat file1 >> file2
```

will do just as well?

or if you want to leave the original two files alone and produce the joined file as a seperate one:

```
cat file1 file2 >> file3
```

Answer (score 0):

A small (cryptic) [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) game :)

```
$ cat 0
  1012055500012221
  2011052210011021
  3010051501010221
  4015051510012201

$ cat 1
  50222111
  60202100
  75222105
  90202125

$ awk 42 0 1
  1012055500012221
  2011052210011021
  3010051501010221
  4015051510012201
  50222111
  60202100
  75222105
  90202125
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted `sed` then here it is:

```
sed '' file{1,2}
```